Handling files via FtpWebRequest
I attempted to upload using FtpWebRequest from D365 crm plugin, but it is failing due to this error(A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.). Any ideas?


using (Stream Stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{    
    Stream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
}
using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{   
    return response.StatusDescription;

}




If you're in Dynamics 365 Online, the plugin can only be registered in sandbox isolation mode, which restricts the protocols it can use externally to HTTP or HTTPS.
As per this blog:

Sandboxed plug-ins and custom workflow activities can access the
network through the HTTP and HTTPS protocols. This capability provides
support for accessing popular web resources like social sites, news
feeds, web services, and more. The following web access restrictions
apply to this sandbox capability.

If your environment is on-prem, then the FTP protocol should be allowed.
Additional documenation:

Your server must have the current TLS and cipher suites.
Only the HTTP and HTTPS protocols are allowed.
Access to localhost (loopback) is not permitted.
IP addresses cannot be used. You must use a named web address that requires DNS name resolution.
Anonymous authentication is supported and recommended. There is no provision for prompting the logged on user for credentials or saving those credentials.
Your server must allow connections from Power Platform and Dynamics 365 services IP address values specified under the AzureCloud service tag.
Other methods of accessing web services include the use of Webhooks and the Azure Service Bus. Refer to the links provided below for more information on those topics.

